# Comparing 2 ArrayList's size and elements continously

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist

I would like to know if there is a way for 2 ArrayLists to be compared continuously until their sizes are the same or their elements are the same. The first ArrayList would have a fixed set of elements (let's say 5 elements). The second ArrayList would be empty and with each user interaction an element would be added to the second ArrayList. When the second ArrayList has the same size as the first ArrayList, a comparison is done to see if both arrayLists are the same.

I have gone through a number of ways to do this:

1. I used a nested loop to compare stored and played Items

   ```
   public int compare(ImageView computer, ImageView player){
   if(player == computer)
       return 1;
   else
       return 2;
   }


   public void checkMatch(){
       for(int x = 0; x < storedList.size(); x++){
           for(int y = 0; y < playedList.size(); y++){
               result = compare(storedList.get(x), playedList.get(y));
               if(result == 1)
                   //Do stuff
               else
                   //End round
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. I then just tried explicitly doing this

   ```
   if(playedList == storedList)
       //do stuff
   else
       //do stuff
   ```
3. All of this may work, but I do not know where to call this for the code to actually wait for all the user input to be done completely. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *(...) I do not know where to call this for the code to actually wait for all the user input to be done completely* - the answer to your question depends on what kind of user input you're talking about exactly? Verbal? Touch? Accelerometer? And so on.

Comment: Have you tried Arrays.deepEquals() ? Also override equals method of the class you are comparing.

Comment: @MH. When an ImageView (acts as a button is clicked) that's the user input

Comment: @dora I have never had of deepEquals till just now :(

Comment: @Tobidae how can you compare two imageviews like you have done in your compare method ? I think that is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few comments on your code:

```
if(playedList == storedList)
```

Will not do what you expect. == is only true if the references are the same, not if the objects are equal. You should use `if(storedList.equals(playedList))` instead.

I'm not sure you need to check the size first (it is done in the equals method anyway) and without the code will be much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll go clean up my code now, this explains a lot of other things

Answer (score 1):

You can check inside button click function where you are saving the secondArraylist items

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             if(secondArrayList.size()==5){
                  compare(); //Call compare method here
              }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think I may have to do this till I figure somethin out thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public int searchlist(ImageView computer){
    for(int x = 0; x < storedList.size(); x++){
    result = compare(storedList.get(x), computer);
    }
}
return result;
}


public void checkMatch(){
            for(int y = 0; y < playedList.size(); y++){
            result = searchlist(playedList.get(y));
            if(result == 1)
                //Do stuff
            else
                //End round
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compare method should be like below
Get the 2 images ID then compare it,

```
public int compare(ImageView computer, ImageView player) {
    if (player.getId() == computer.getId())
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

Comment: An Image View is in a way an Object so I guess any objects can be compared so far as they are from the same class type (Strings, It's,  e.t.c)

Comment: yes, they can be compared. but i don't think that the comparision you wrote above would return the result you want.